# I need help with a 12 piece wooden puzzle

Tags: puzzle-identification, mechanical-puzzles, burr-puzzle

12 pieces. See picture. Can’t find any solutions online.
[image]

Comment: Try [12 piece burr puzzles](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/375346950167119044/). Some are solved on YouTube.

Comment: I can’t find any on YouTube that have these variety of shapes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the finished puzzle is similar to the second picture on [this page](https://www.puzzlemuseum.com/month/picm06/200612chinese3.htm) (except your pieces are all the same length) so you have 4 pieces along each axis, each parallel set arranged as 1x4. In your picture, the top two and bottom four pieces form the 3 centre pairs, the other six pieces are the outer ones (the shorter ones in the page I linked to).

Comment: @Bass Your tag edits are a bit self-contradictory. Does the OP want us to identify the puzzle type (as suggested by the [tag:puzzle-identification] tag) or do they already know what it is (as suggested by the [tag:burr-puzzle] tag) and want to know how to solve it?

Comment: @Randal'Thor There are hundreds of variants of Burr puzzles (just like there are hundreds of distinct puzzles classified as twisty-puzzles), and it could be that this particular one was marketed under a specific name or was made by a specific puzzle maker. Knowing its name or origin would help with finding an online solution. I see no contradiction there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [Burr Tools](http://burrtools.sourceforge.net/) I've made an image of the solution steps.

> [image]

Comment: Very nice, but it is not immediately apparent which piece type each color represents. Also, the pieces in the image appear to have overall dimensions of 6x1x1, whereas yours are 5x1x1. This, of course, does not affect the solution.

Comment: That’s SO fantastic! Totally worked! I’m so impressed. The colour coding really helped and I could deduce which colour was assigned to each part. A little tweaking required but considering I had no idea what the final shape was supposed to be this is a great outcome. Very grateful!!!! Thank you!!!!!